# Elastic Search - Keyword Stuffing and Scoring

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Need Help with Keyword Stuffing.

Scenario: I have 2 Presentations, with the titles as follows:

Example 1:
Presentation #1: "Bake Cake Bake bake cake cake cake bake"
Presentation #2: "Bake Cake"
Now, when I search with the text 'Bake cake', the result must return with the most appropriate match, ie. Presentation #2 should be listed at the top/first.

Example 2:
Presentation #1: "Bake Cake Bake bake cake cake cake bake"
Presentation #2: "Bake Cake"
Presentation #3: "bake A cake"
Now, when I search with the text 'Bake cake', the result must return with the most appropriate match, ie. Presentation #2 should be listed at the top/first, followed by Presentation #3, and last should be Presentation #1.

Case sensitivity does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I will explain "How Elasticsearch calculates the score" and then I will share a solution for your specific case.

**How Elasticsearch calculates the score**

> Elasticsearch uses a scoring algorithm called TF-IDF (Term
> Frequency-Inverse Document Frequency) to calculate the relevance score
> of documents that match a query.
>
> TF (Term Frequency) is a measure of **how often a term appears** in a
> document. The more often a term appears in a document, the higher the
> TF score will be for that term in that document.
>
> IDF (Inverse Document Frequency) is a measure of **how rare a term is**
> across all documents in a collection. The rarer a term is, the higher
> the IDF score will be for that term.
>
> When Elasticsearch calculates the relevance score of a document for a
> query, it takes into account both the TF scores of the query terms in
> the document, as well as the IDF scores of the query terms across all
> documents. The final score is a combination of the TF and IDF scores,
> often represented as TF-IDF.
>
> Additionally, Elasticsearch has some feature like Field-length norm,
> which can boost score for shorter fields and some other feature like
> query Norm, which normalize the score based on the number of query.
>
> It's also possible to customize the scoring algorithm by providing a
> custom script to the query, this allow even more flexibility when
> trying to match your use case.

Solution for your cases:
Case 1: Sorting by **asc** order will solve your problem.
Case 2: Use the [stop token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) to remove stop words. Here are the stop words

```
a, an, and, are, as, at, be, but, by, for, if, in, into, is, it, no, not, of, on, or, such, that, the, their, then, there, these, they, this, to, was, will, with
```

Here is an example for you:

**#create an analyzer before indexing**

```
PUT test_bake_cake
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "custom_analyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "stop"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**#index your data**

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_bake_cake", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "text" : "Bake Cake Bake bake cake cake cake bake" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_bake_cake", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "text" : "Bake Cake" }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test_bake_cake", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "text" : "bake A cake" }
```

**#search your data**

```
GET test_bake_cake/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "bake cake"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The output will be as you want. Presentation #2, #3 and #1, like in the screenshot.
[image]